# Initializing a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there another (more beautiful) way to initialize this Javascript array?

```
    var counter = [];
    counter["A"] = 0; 
    counter["B"] = 0;
    counter["C"] = 0;
    counter["D"] = 0;
    counter["E"] = 0;
    counter["F"] = 0;
    counter["G"] = 0;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A. That doesn't work, or at least not the way you'd hope it to. You initialized an array when what you're most likely looking for is a hash. `counter` will still return `[]` and have a length of `0` unless you change the first line to `counter = {};`. The properties will exist, but it's a confusing use of `[]` to store key-value pairs.

B:

```
var counter = {A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, E: 0, F: 0, G: 0};
```

Comment: -1 because just about everything stated above is wrong. It does "work", the properties are assigned. By "counter will still return 0" presumably you mean `counter.toString()`, but that will return an empty string (per EMCA-262 §15.4.4.2 since *counter* has no numeric properties). If *counter* is initialised as an object, then `counter.toString()` will not return "0", it will return `[object Object]` per ECMA-262 §15.2.4.2.

Comment: Actually it was dumber: running his code in the console gave me `0` because the last line was `counter["G"] = 0;`. I was referring to the console output, in any case. You are right about being able to assign almost anything as a property to an object, of course, so I reworded that portion to point out the desirability of using `{}` over `[]` as an associative array, if for no other reason than least surprise.

Answer (score 13):

Use an object literal instead of an array, like this:

```
var counter = {A:0,B:0,C:0}; // and so on
```

Then access the properties with dot notation:

```
counter.A;  // 0
```

...or square bracket notation:

```
counter['A'];  // 0
```

You'll primarily use Arrays for numeric properties, though it is possible to add non-numeric properties as you were.

Comment: +1 for object literals.. i didn't know about those; very cool

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter={A:0,B:0,C:0,D:0,E:0,F:0,G:0};
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to use an object for this:

```
    var counter = {
        A: 0, 
        B: 0, 
        C: 0, 
        D: 0, 
        E: 0, 
        F: 0, 
        G: 0
     };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted an array full of zeroes, `Array(5).fill(0)` would do the trick.