# Creating an associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wasn't sure what to call it for the title,

How can I create an array like this in JavaScript?

```
var per_kg_list = new Array(
    '03749' => '3.000',
    '03750' => '4.000',
    '03751' => '5.000',
);
```

Comment: basically you are looking for key-value pairs in javascript, you can refer this answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196212/how-to-create-dictionary-and-add-key-value-pairs-dynamically-in-javascript

Comment: Take a tour of the basics here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals

Comment: The canonical is *[How to do associative array/hashing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an array of objects containing key-value pairs, like this:

```
var per_kg_list = [
    {'03749': '3.000'},
    {'03750': '4.000'},
    {'03751': '5.000'}
];
```

Alternatively, you can have an object containing key-value pairs, like this:

```
var per_kg_list = {
    '03749': '3.000',
    '03750': '4.000',
    '03751': '5.000'
};
```

Comment: What was the purpose of editing my answer to add one whitespace character?

Comment: So I could remove my downvote since you updated your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, array doesn't allow to use string as indexes. You may consider to use dictionary:

```
var per_kg_list = {};
per_kg_list['03749'] = '3.000';
per_kg_list['03750'] = '4.000';
per_kg_list['03751'] = '5.000';
```

Comment: It's just called an object in JS

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah. True.

Comment: Also, Array extends Object, so it can be used as map, but you shouldn't. It's really using strings and the keys that parse to integers are taken into account when calculating the length property, more or less Try `a=[0]; a["0"] = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Someone [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019394/initializing-a-javascript-array) the best way to initializing a JavaScript array with values:

```
var per_kg_list = {'03749': '3.000', '03750': '4.000', '03751': '5.000'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use associative array notations. They are just JavaScript objects with properties:

```
var set = new Object();
set['Document language'] = 'HTML5';
set['Styling language'] = 'CSS3';
set['JavaScript library'] = 'jQuery';
set['Other'] = 'Usability and accessibility';
```

Comment: They are not equivalent

Comment: @JuanMendes Okay .. I am just learning JavaScript and this is my first JavaScript answer .. can u pls let me know where is the issue ?

Comment: Array extends Object with methods like push, pop, and you would give it numeric indices. If you don't need that behavior,  you should just use object.http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Javascript_Object_and_Array.html

Comment: The comment about the longhand for maps is wrong in the article you linked to, not sure if it's a typo

Comment: If you just change your code to say `=new Object ()` or `={}`, then it would be correct. Your code will work but you should understand the difference between object and arrays

Comment: Here's a link from Google's style guide, explaining why you shouldn't use arrays as associative maps http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Associative_Arrays#Associative_Arrays